# How to count how many areas there are in a grid with a 'w' in it

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a program where i read in a grid file with just 'w' and 'b's in it of size 10. I want to know how i can count how many areas of connected white (or w's) there are and what the number of w's are inside of each of the areas. I have the main method, a method that reads in the grid, a way to count every w in the whole grid, but do not know how to count the areas and how to specify how many whites are in each area. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program {
    private int xD[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1};
    private int yD[] = {1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1};

    public Program() {
        n = 0;
        k = 0;
        CountSpace = 0;
    }

    private char[][] getGrid() { //Takes in the grid, counts the number of squares
        String fileName = "grid.txt";
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            String line = "";
            line = input.nextLine();
            line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            n = line.length();
            grid = new char[n][n];
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                if (y > 0) {
                    line = input.nextLine();
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                    grid[x][y] = line.charAt(x);
                }
            }

            visited = new boolean[n][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    visited[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return grid;
    }

    private void display() //Displays the grid that was read in from the text file
    {
        System.out.println("Grid : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[j][i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("# Spaces: " + CountSpace);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) //main method
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        char[][] temp = p.getGrid();
        p.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code doing presently?  What all have you tried before?

Comment: The code presently just counts every 'w' space. So it reads in a grid, it runs through the grid marking every white spaces as visited, and counts the total number of white space

Comment: I would love any insight you might have @PaulBeverage

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like labeling the connected components in a binary image. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: That seems to be for an image, i am not doing it for an image. I'm wondering how to implement it for this two dimensional array and print it out the number of areas and the number of white squares in each area to the use

Comment: Any help would be awesome @MFisherKDX

Comment: @student100 you have a 2D array of character, where each char is either a `b` (black) or a `w` (white). A binary image can be represented as a 2D array of 1's and 0's where 1 is white and 0 is black. So it's really the same problem.

Comment: i see that and its a good point however I am still not sure how to implement it

Comment: @student100 Have you studied graphs? In my opinion the easiest way to code this is a graph search where `w`s are vertices and two adjacent `w`s in your array are joined by an edge. Read the "algorithms" subsection in the Wikipedia article referenced above and follow the "breadth first search" link. You will even find code.